# What does this MySQL statement do?

Tags: mysql, cross-join

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `PREFIX_tab_lang` (`id_tab`, `id_lang`, `name`)
    (SELECT `id_tab`, id_lang, (SELECT tl.`name`
        FROM `PREFIX_tab_lang` tl
        WHERE tl.`id_lang` = (SELECT c.`value`
            FROM `PREFIX_configuration` c
            WHERE c.`name` = 'PS_LANG_DEFAULT' LIMIT 1) AND tl.`id_tab`=`PREFIX_tab`.`id_tab`)
    FROM `PREFIX_lang` CROSS JOIN `PREFIX_tab`);
```

It's from an opensource project,and no documentation available.

Especially,what does `cross-join` mean? I've only used join/left join .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), it's basically a synonym for `INNER JOIN`, and `INNER JOIN` is the same as just `JOIN` (that is, "`INNER`" is the default).

Comment: So it's yet another a synonym for `JOIN` since `INNER JION` is the same as `JOIN`?

Comment: Yeah, I just added that to my answer. In "standard" SQL, `CROSS JOIN` is actually different to `INNER JOIN`, since `INNER JOIN` usually requires the predicate (`ON`) whereas `CROSS JOIN` does not.

Comment: How about `CROSS JOIN` in "standard" SQL?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo, so it's a synonym for `cartesian join`?

Comment: @user198729: Yes it is. It is MySQL that used the similar syntax for `INNER JOIN`s and `CROSS JOIN`s. Technically INNER JOINs should require the `ON` predicate as codeka noted in a comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-join: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join

The query inserts into `PREFIX_tab_lang` the results of a select. The select is just two columns from the cross-product. The third column -- name -- actually comes from a totally different select, which is also pretty straight-forward except that one of it's `where` conditions is yet another select.

In short, this is one of the worst queries I've ever seen. It's preformance is probably horrible, and it should be replaced by a bit of TRANSATION-protected code or, at the very least, a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually consider the following queries to be synonyms in MySQL:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        Table1
CROSS JOIN  Table2;

SELECT      *
FROM        Table1, Table2;

SELECT      *
FROM        Table1
INNER JOIN  Table2;

SELECT      *
FROM        Table1
JOIN        Table2;
```

Test Case:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id int, value varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE Table2 (id int, t1_id int);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 'Value 1');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2, 'Value 2');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (3, 'Value 3');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (4, 'Value 4');

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (6, 3);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (7, 4);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (8, 4);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (9, 4);
```

All four queries would return the following result set:

```
+------+---------+------+-------+
| id   | value   | id   | t1_id |
+------+---------+------+-------+
|    1 | Value 1 |    1 |     1 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    1 |     1 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    1 |     1 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    1 |     1 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    2 |     1 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    2 |     1 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    2 |     1 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    2 |     1 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    3 |     2 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    3 |     2 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    3 |     2 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    3 |     2 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    4 |     2 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    4 |     2 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    4 |     2 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    4 |     2 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    5 |     2 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    5 |     2 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    5 |     2 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    5 |     2 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    6 |     3 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    6 |     3 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    6 |     3 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    6 |     3 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    7 |     4 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    7 |     4 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    7 |     4 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    7 |     4 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    8 |     4 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    8 |     4 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    8 |     4 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    8 |     4 |
|    1 | Value 1 |    9 |     4 |
|    2 | Value 2 |    9 |     4 |
|    3 | Value 3 |    9 |     4 |
|    4 | Value 4 |    9 |     4 |
+------+---------+------+-------+
36 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```